# Looking for recommendation for PHP app hosting with (relatively) painless scalability

Tags: php, web-hosting, cloud-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

We're a pre-launch startup with a LAMP based application. We're looking for recommendations for hosting services for our upcoming beta launch. Our main requirements:

1. LAMP support
2. Ability to schedule/start daily/hourly server-initiated batch jobs against our databases.
3. Relatively painless scalability when we grow - adding servers/databases/bandwidth without having to re-architecture everything or cause major outages.
4. Support for Wordpress

Pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: no one can give a recommendation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check [Media Temple](http://mediatemple.net/). Their [DV](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/dv/) service should have everything you need and is easily scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you would be looking to scale out, a cloud provider such as Rackspace or Amazon may be a good choice as well.  Providers such as these allow you to scale on demand and offer quite a few options to both scale out (additional servers) and scale up (grow your existing server).  In addition to scaling the server infrastructure, you have options for scaling the network infrastructure as well such as bandwidth, firewalls, and load balancers.

Answer (score 0):

[www.pagodabox.com](http://www.pagodabox.com) is not lamp. They are a pretty sweet app hosting platform. Easy to scale both the database and the application. What you will be most interested in is there database tool.

go to http://www.pagodabox.com/videos and watch the "Opening a Database Tunnel" video.